# Разрешение на изменение, но не удаление в каталогах Samba

Tags: права, samba, debian

Как настроить Samb-овские каталоги, чтобы файлы можно было в каталог изменять, но не удалять?

Как в Debian 5 настроить расшаренные Samb-овские каталоги, чтобы файлы можно было в каталог писать, изменять, но не удалять? Чтобы нельзя было по сети грохнуть файл, а изменить оный можно.

Интересует решение не для одного конкретного файла, а чтобы все файлы в каталоге данного пользоваетеля обладали таким свойством - можно создать, изменить, но не удалить!

Answer (score 2):

```
chmod 655 <каталог> -->Неверно!
```

Для владельца нет доступа обращения к метаданным каталога.

В линуксе есть такое понятие как модификация (изменения) файла, если у вас разрешены права на модификацию файла, то вы можете его переименовать, изменить и удалить - по отдельности никак!

`chmod 1777` - эти права на каталог разрешат всем изменять любые файлы, но удалять файлы из этого каталога смогут только лишь их владельцы и root естественно! Такие права я ставлю на папку общего назначения...

Answer (score 2):

В линуксе права на удаление файла = права на создание файла = права на запись в каталог где этот файл расположен, с одним исключением - бит t для каталога запрещает удаление чужих файлов.

В samba есть дополнительные настройки, которые проверяются сервером smbd.

Смотрите описание [create mask](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html#CREATEMAS) чтобы разрешить всем пользователям изменять чужие файлыи [inherit owner](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html#INHERITOWNER) - там кажется как раз про ваш случай написано

Answer (score 0):

```
chmod 655 <каталог>
```